# Send ip packet via kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm writing a kernel module which creates an ip packet and sends it to the required destination. I'm using the function `ip_forward()` declared in `<net/ip.h>`. When I try to compile the code, I get an error:

> "ip_forward" undefined!

Comment: in which header file it is declared......by which function are you sending your ip packet........

Comment: It is declared in net/ip.h and defined in /net/ipv4/ip_forward.c

Answer (score 1):

`ip_forward` isn't exported (no `EXPORT_SYMBOL`), so you can't use it from kernel modules.

It's also an internal function of the IP stack, not meant to be called directly. It may have all sorts of assumptions, which would give you trouble.

Perhaps try `ip_queue_xmit`, though I'm not 100% sure it's usable.

Comment: `ip_queue_xmit` compiled without any errors. But when I tried to insert the module, the system hangs and I've to reboot. I'm calling the function as follows:

struct flowi *fl=NULL;  fl->u.ip4.saddr=123456;  
fl->u.ip4.daddr=234567;  
if(ip_queue_xmit(skb,fl)>=0)  
  printk(KERN_EMERG "Packet transmitted");  
else  
  printk(KERN_EMERG "Error");

Comment: You'll need to debug... But the sequence `struct flowi *fl=NULL; fl->u.ip4.saddr=123456` will surely crash on NULL-pointer dereference.